# Update SQL server table from an Excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, unpivot

I went through a few links and some questions on Stackoverflow and nothing seems to help.
I tried [this](https://blogs.office.com/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/) but I do not have `Get & Transform` ribbon in my Excel.
I tried [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) but I do not have `Query Editor` ribbon in my Excel.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 300+ rows that needs to be added to a SQL Server table.
My table needs to be unpivoted first. For e.g.,

This is my current format on Excel:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

The columns become attributes and the corresponding rows become their values. Once that is done, I want to insert this "unpivoted" table to my SQL Server table.

I already have a table in place with some information. I need to update that table with these values. Just push this whole thing in there.

For the sake of this problem, let's assume that all the variables are nvarchar(50).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just upload the table as is to the server and do the [unpivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) there.

Comment: That might be a problem because of already existent rows in the table. There are over 3000 rows in the SQL server table that is unpivoted and looks like the second image.

Comment: Then upload it to the server using a temp table or a table variable. Unpivot the data in there and then insert the unpivoted data into the final (destination) table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys. Just a little bit of fooling around and the nudge from @Ralph helped me figure this out.
Right click the database -> Tasks -> Import
Go through the wizard. When it asks for source and destination files, I selected the Excel sheet as source, Clicked on `Edit Mappings` and clicked on `Edit SQL` button.
Now I can edit the query to make it do what I want to do.
Thank you.